# Retrofitting Dependency Injection and Automated Testing: Factory and Load/List method confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am working on a new phase of an MVC project.  The first phase was fairly small and not very complex.  The next phase will be very complex and much bigger.  During the first phase we discussed and then discarded the idea of doing thorough automated testing for various reasons.

With the new phase, I want our team to invest in automated testing.  I don't think we can do anything useful without dependency injection since we will want to stub out the database work to make our tests controllable.

What I struggle with is retrofitting dependency injection into my business layer.  Our existing business objects have state, behavior, and are responsible for loading instances of themselves (via static methods).  For example, we might have this over-simplified example:

```
public class User
{
    public User(string userName)
    {}

    public bool Authenticate()
    {}

    public static User GetByUserName(string userName)
    {
      //Do some DB querying, and then map the data object to a new instance:
      UserRepository repository = new UserRepository();
      var databaseObject = repository.list(u => u.userName = userName);
      User user = new User();
      user.userName = databaseObject.userName;
      // populate other fields
      return user;
    }
 }
```

From a quick glance, it seems I will need to:

1. Inject the Repository as a dependency in the constructor
2. Change the GetByUserName to no longer be a static method in User
3. Do some sort of factory to be able to create an instance of User in the GetByUserName method

I can't figure out how to do all of this in a reasonable manner.  #1 is trivial, but #2 and #3 are less trivial.  Here's what I'm thinking about how to do #2:

1. Leave the structure largely as is and just remove the static keyword.  This means that in order to get a User by username you have to create an instance of the User object then call the GetByUserName method.  This does not pass my highly sophisticated smell test.
2. Move the responsibility for loading and saving Users to some sort of UserCollection object.  This seems dubious to me because it means almost every business object would need an underlying collection object, and because it would make my domain model more anemic.
3. Interface with the repository directly.  Right now the controller might call User.GetByUserName() to get a User domain object back to do some work.  Instead the controller would be aware of the repository and call Repository.list().  That seems leaky to me - suddenly the Controller feels like it's doing businessy things.

Then there's #3.  It seems like my options are either to use my IOC container to inject factory methods (e.g. autofac factory delegate) or to manually create the factories for each object.  It seems leaky to use the autofac methodology because then I have to either use autofac in my unit tests or stub out a factory delegate for each object.  It seems troubling to make factories for all objects because at some point I'm imposing significant workload on developers just to be able to use DI without being aware of my IOC container.

I've done what I can to search for these subjects but I'm really not seeing a lot of concrete examples that don't involve the drawbacks above.

What are some techniques for solving #2 and #3 without losing "Good Design" or making "Too Much Work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `User` class should not know about the repository IMHO.  If you wire in the repository you make it difficult to unit-test the `User` class and would create a circular reference if you ever decide to put the repository in a different assembly.

A typical design is to have an `IUserRepository` interface that defines your CRUD methods (e.g. `GetUserByUserName`) and one or more `UserRepository` classes that point to actual data source(s).

When you have anything that needs to work with a `UserRepository` (like a Controller) inject it as an `IUserRepository`.  That way you can unit test the controller with mock/stub repository.

Your repositories will know about your business classes, and may be (loosely) coupled to other repositories (e.g. a `Role` repository may be injected with an `IUserRepository` to get the users in a role.

If you want to start with one "master" repository for all classes that's fine, but you run the risk of having to split out the repositories later (which may not be a huge deal).

So I would recommend option #2 and sub-option #2 (calling it `UserRepository` versus `UserCollection`).

Comment: I guess #2 and #3 are kind of similar in this respect.  My concern is that it feels leaky to have the controllers interacting with the repository -- the controllers therefore are "doing things" or at least have the appearance of doing things.  Suppose the controller has a Logon() method which (somewhere - either in business or in the controller) first calls User.Authenticate() and then if successful, gets the user via GetByUserName, updates their last logon attribute, then calls Save().  If the User class doesn't know about repository, then the controller is doing businessy things here, right?

Comment: Sure, you could have another layer that's your "business logic" layer that the controllers deal with - the main point is that the models should not have references to the repositories (theirs or any others).  That should be controlled at a higher level.  or at the very worst use interfaces to inject the repositories so you can mock it out and avoid circular references.

Comment: I have decided to try adding a "service layer" or "Business logic layer" to the application which will handle some of the stuff currently in the business objects and which will have repositories injected (though I was almost swayed by Ayende against repositories - turned out our needs are too nebulous to know if we can safely get rid of them because EF might not do everything we need).  I am willing to end up with an anemic set of business objects as the tradeoff.  Marking this as the answer since it ultimately is the direction I'm intending to go.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How you implement this mostly comes down to where you want to put that logic of retrieving the database object from the `UserRepository` and populating a `User` instance from it.  Some people like to have "smart" models that can retrieve their own data, but others don't.

It sounds like you want to have a somewhat smart `User` class.  I think you can accomplish that by injecting the `UserRepository` into the constructor of the `User` class, and instead of creating *another* `User` instance, just use the repository to populate this `User` instance.

Below is an example implementation.  My expectation is that you are using an IoC container, and that you'll register the IUserRepository interface in it.  I assume that you'll want an interface for the user repository, since you might want to mock it out for unit testing, etc.

```
public class User
{
    public User(IUserRepository repository, string userName)
    {
      var databaseObject = repository.list(u => u.userName = userName);

      this.userName = databaseObject.userName;
      // populate other fields
    }

    public bool Authenticate()
    {}
 }
```

Now you should be able to instantiate a User object through the IoC container.  For example, if you're using Ninject, then I think the syntax would be the following:

```
var user = kernel.Get<User>(new ConstructorArgument("userName", "<actual username value>"));
```

With Unity I believe it would be something like this:

```
container.Resolve<User>(new ParameterOverride("userName", "<actual username value>"))
```

Depending on your IoC container, you may also need to register the User class, even though it's not implementing an interface and you're not really trying to swap it out with anything.  It might be necessary in order to wire up your registered IUserRepository with the User class's constructor parameter.

If you really want to keep your instantiation code clean, then you could keep the static method on the User class and just have it do the one line above.

Disclaimer: I've not tested this code.

Comment: I am hoping to avoid using the IoC container directly to obtain instances.  This to me means that your unit tests have to use IoC.  Or is that not a bad thing?

Comment: Hmm, generally unit tests don't *need* to use an IoC container.  You should be able to manually construct an object, passing in a mock implementation of an interface for instance, without using an IoC container.  If I were writing a unit test for the code above, I could do something like `var user = new User(new MockUserRepository(), "<test username value>");`.  You could also manually construct your objects this way in your application code, if you really wanted to, or you could have your `User` constructor check for a null parameter and, in that case, create a `UserRepository` instance.

Comment: Yeah, the repository mocking I get.  But if in my business classes or controller I have to create an instance and use the IOC container to do so, then that means my unit tests need to configure the IOC container so that stuff like container.Resolve<User>(new ParameterOverride...) will still work in unit tests.  Abstracting that out to a factory leads to my factory question above.

Comment: What some people do is have those dependencies provided to the controllers and/or business classes as either constructor arguments or properties, and to generally instantiate those using IoC.  So you could feed in an `IUserRepository` to your controller via constructor argument, and just pass that in to the `User` constructor without involving an IoC container.  Additionally, you can use the MVC framework's `DependencyResolver` class to have the MVC framework instantiate your controllers using your IoC container, if you want.